# Custom event in JavaScript like onReadyEvent()

Tags: javascript, events, google-hangouts

I need similar functionality to its own events, such as the Hangout API (and probably many other APIs).

For example, is there an event: onApiReady, which is invoked when the API is initialized.

I found a great tutorial -> http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/ but do not really know how to let you create and recall of events spinning each object.

Regards.

Comment: An event emitter is usually implemented by having a backing object that maps event names to an array of event handlers. You have a `on(eventName,handler)` method that pushes a new handler to the array in the eventName key and a `trigger(eventName)` method that calls the handlers on the event.

Comment: I guess I was able to implement, but do not really know how to call only once for an event and then be able to relate to him from anywhere in the script, something like: ENTIRE_SCRIPT.fire('onApiReady'), and then in another file ENTIRE_SCRIPT.addEventListener('onApiReady', callback);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Javascript Solution

You have to paste the following code before your script file:

```
function EventTarget(){
    this._listeners = {};
}

EventTarget.prototype = {

    constructor: EventTarget,

    addListener: function(type, listener){
        if (typeof this._listeners[type] == "undefined"){
            this._listeners[type] = [];
        }

        this._listeners[type].push(listener);
    },

    fire: function(event){
        if (typeof event == "string"){
            event = { type: event };
        }
        if (!event.target){
            event.target = this;
        }

        if (!event.type){  //falsy
            throw new Error("Event object missing 'type' property.");
        }

        if (this._listeners[event.type] instanceof Array){
            var listeners = this._listeners[event.type];
            for (var i=0, len=listeners.length; i < len; i++){
                listeners[i].call(this, event);
            }
        }
    },

    removeListener: function(type, listener){
        if (this._listeners[type] instanceof Array){
            var listeners = this._listeners[type];
            for (var i=0, len=listeners.length; i < len; i++){
                if (listeners[i] === listener){
                    listeners.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, include this

```
var target = new EventTarget();
function handleEvent(event){
    alert("API is ready ;)");
};
target.addListener("onApiReady", handleEvent);
```

at the top of your script.

And then, put the following code at the end of your API or when you are initializing it.

```
target.fire("onApiReady");
```

JsFiddle:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/8nYfK/5/</kbd>. (*In my demo, I've used `setTimeout` to emulate script loading*)

Comment: Exactly what I mean, but how can I implement it without using external libraries? I would like to do this without using jQuery. document.on doesn't work.

Comment: @Unstoppable, I'm coming up with an answer. Plz wait ;)